# Detected the Mesh's Specific material under the click in unity

Tags: unity, c#

I have a mesh in unity which is made of several materails. Now if i click on it on a specific location of the mesh, i want to pick its selected materail. Actually the mesh itself have several materials. One way is that i the modelling tools should split the object according to materials but this will probably a lot of work and it may cause decrease the FPS.

Comment: [Does this answer your question](https://discussions.unity.com/t/raycasthit-triangleindex-and-submeshes-which-submesh/47763/2)?

Comment: Is this something you want to do in the Editor or while the game is running?